# Select rows in Pandas and iterate thru them to change value in column based in value in another row

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame where every row represents an object.
I want to select all rows that have a specific value in a column. Then I want to iterate thru the selected rows and and add a value in a column based on a value in another column on the row.

I would use loc to select the rows, but then I have no idea how to iterate over them to check value and change them.

This might be a broad question, but I am new to Pandas. I did search for similar question, but did not find what I was searching for.

Example Data

| id | name | city | address | is customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Berlin | bla |  |
| 2 | Jake | Paris | bla |  |
| 3 | Jim | Berlin | Club |  |

I want to select only rows with "Berlin" as city.
Then lookup the name in the list of customers:

```
list_of_customers = ["John","Jake"]
```

And if the name is found ad a "True" in the column "is customer"

| id | name | city | address | is customer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Berlin | bla | True |
| 2 | Jake | Paris | bla |  |
| 3 | Jim | Berlin | Club |  |

I prefer to change the original DF not create a new one.

Comment: Please add sample of your data and expected output

Comment: My problem is less selecting the rows, more how to iterate over them to check and change values.

Comment: Does my answer below helps?

Comment: Honestly I don't understand where you add the value for the column "ID".

Comment: Now that you clarified your question I updated my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you clarified your question I can help:

```
import numpy as np
list_of_customers = ["john","jake"]
df ['is customer'] = np.where(df['name'].str.lower().isin(list_of_customers), True, False)
```

Comment: Generally you don't want to use numpy's `np.where`, just pandas' logical indexing: `df[df['car'] == 'fiat']` will return you the rows, filtered by conditions.

Comment: That works nice! I just have a little problem. If the name is spelled in all caps then I don't get a match. Is there any way to have a .lower() on the field to compare to the list?

Comment: See updated answer for lower case